# Unpack WinRAR in background

Tags: winrar

I want to call WinRAR from the context menu, and select "unpack to folder", and have WinRAR run in minimized state. It this possible without manually pressing the "Background" button on the Winrar unpack dialog?

Answer (score 2):

1. Select *Options → Settings* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Switch to the *Compression* tab and click `[Create default…]`
3. Switch to the *Advanced* tab and check the `Background archiving` box
4. Click `[OK]` twice

Now WinRAR should always default to background mode and minimized to the notification area.

You can also create a separate profile specifically for running the background and add that to the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

Your best bet is to add an additional context menu item that points to a different piece of software, that does allow you to run it in the background.

Alternatively you could do something similar that points to a AutoHotkey script or similar, that will press <kbd>Background</kbd> for you.

<sup>[*Help pages for "Command line syntax" for WinRAR*](http://www.winrar-tr.com/winrar/Help/ENG/html/HELPCommandLineSyntax.htm)</sup>